# Intel RealSense java support

Tags: java, intel, realsense

I would like to use Intel RealSense for voice recognition. And in documentation described java support there are few examples with java code, but there are not any library for java.

This code is in documentation, but where can I find this library with PXCMSession for java?

```
PXCMSession session=PXCMSession.CreateInstance();
...
PXCMSession.ImplVersion ver=session.QueryVersion();
System.out.printf("SDK Version %d.%d%n",ver.major,ver.minor);
...
session.close();



PXCMSession session=PXCMSession.CreateInstance();
...
PXCMSession.ImplVersion ver=session.QueryVersion();
System.out.printf("SDK Version %d.%d%n",ver.major,ver.minor);
...
session.close();
```

May be somebody work with it

Answer (score 1):

Java is not yet complete/supported in the beta SDK.

Answer (score 1):

There is now limited support for Java in the Intel RealSense SDK (Gold R2):
The Java Library is at :

```
$(RSSDK_DIR)/framework/common/pxcclr.java/bin/x64:
libpxcclr.java.jar
libpxcclr.jni.dll
```

Notice there is only x64, not 32 bit support.

Also checkout the SDK [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/manuals_interface_and_function_reference_core.html)

Comment: Hi, do you know what is the status of the Java support for RealSense for now? Seems a bit unclear in the documentation. Have you been using it with good results?